# What is the relation of the butler to the protagonist?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, estranged

The movie Estranged (2015) is a tense thriller, and my question spoils the mystery.

Why is the butler sympathetic and why does he help? Further...

> Why does he go along with her torment at all? He hastily explains things, sort of, but I never understood if he was part of her family before the servants took over or if he was also a butler before the takeover.

The writing seems a bit loose on motivations and whatnot, but I still feel like there was something the writers were including that I missed.